# Declaration incompatible

Tags: c++, header

Im about to learn a bit C++. I am used to Java and Python and im very confused with the whole header stuff.

Utils.cpp:

```
#include "Utils.h"
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string dst = "";

string Utils::getDst() const {
    return dst;
}

string Utils::getExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    return string(buffer);
}

char* Utils::getCwd() {
    return _getcwd(0, 0);
}
```

Utils.h:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

class Utils
{
private:
    string dst;
public:
    string getDst() const;
    char* getCwd();
    string getExePath();
};

#endif
```

Debugging isn't a problem. But it runs a older version, where i didn't implement the `#getDst()` and `#getExePath()`. These errors occur when building the project causing it to fail:
[image: Exceptions]

Comment: You just started learning C++ and you're already including Windows.h etc... would you learn how to drive in a formula 1 car? Start with the basics. Build a "Hello World" program and add things bit by bit. There are many unnecessary includes in your header file. You should only need `<string>`. Unless you are using <cstring>, but then you don't want `using namespace std;` (which is bad practice anyhow).

Comment: In `Utils.h`, write `std::string` where you have `string`. Yes, you have `using namespace std;` - but that line is *after* `Utils.h` is included.

Comment: The only include that i wasn't using was iostream. I used it previously for debugging but i forgot to delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik.
My problem was in my Utils.h.

new Utils.h:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

class Utils
{
private:
    std::string dst;
public:
    std::string getDst() const;
    char* getCwd();
    std::string getExePath();
};

#endif
```

i forgot the `std::` before the string. I also could just add `using namespace std;` in the `Utils.h`

Comment: You shouldn't include files you don't directly use in your header file. That's bad design. Only include what's needed for the declaration. You can include what you want in the definition in the cpp file.

Comment: I recommend putting in `using namespace std;` only if you have been programming in C++ for at least 10 years and really understand what that does to your code.